# Client Acknowledge in camel-kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I'm using camel-kafka version `2.14.3` . I used client acknowledge while reading from ibm MQ by creating the bean as follows

```
<bean id="ibmMQwithClientAck" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
            <property name="acknowledgementModeName"
                value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
            <property name="connectionFactory">
                <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
                    <property name="transportType" value="<transportType>" />
                    <property name="hostName" value="<hostName>" />
                    <property name="port" value="<port>" />
                    <property name="channel" value="<channel>" />
                    <property name="queueManager" value="<queueManager>" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm looking for client commit in camel-kafka. Can this be accomplished from consumer itself, or something needs to configured at the kafka cluster end?

I'm using camel-kafka version `2.14.3` .
Below is the kafka URI :

```
<from uri="kafka:{brokerlist}?topic={topic-name}&amp;zookeeperHost={zookeeperHost}&amp;zookeeperPort={zookeeperPort}&amp;groupId={groupId-name}&amp;consumerStreams=2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use manual commit via `allowManualCommit=true`, see the docs at: https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/kafka-component.html

At the section: https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/kafka-component.html#_using_manual_commit_with_kafka_consumer

Comment: Thanks for answering. Manual commit seems to be available only after 2.21 camel-version. I'm using 2.14.3 version.

Comment: Camel 2.14.x rather old from 2015. I suggest to look into using a newer Camel version if possible, certainly for new development.